# How to create string in Excel INDIRECT function to dynamically reference cells in an external spreadsheet 

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I can use an external reference easily in Excel 2010 like this

Cell A1 : `='BLAH.XLSX'!Fees[[#Totals],[Billable Hours]]`

but lets say B1 contains `FOO.XLSX`

I now want A1 to be

```
='FOO.XLS'!Fees[[#Totals],[Billable Hours]]
```

I tried the indirect function

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'", B1, "'!Fees[[#Totals],[Billable Hours]]"))
```

But this just gives a #REF error, but it resolves *(I used the show steps function in excel)*
to:

```
=INDIRECT("'FOO.XLSX'!Fees[[#Totals],[Billable Hours]]")
```

I've tried (played with) a number of things but nothing gives me the reference correctly

suchas `=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("='", B1, "'!Fees[[#Totals],[Billable Hours]]"))` which resolves to

```
=INDIRECT("='FOO.XLSX'!Fees[[#Totals],[Billable Hours]]")
```

Also I want to avoid VBA to avoid security warnings/dialogs etc., but will accept this if that's the the only way

I feel I'm really close

Comment: Indirect returns #REF if the second workbook is closed.  Does it work when it's open?

Comment: @PreetSangha: Still looking for a VBA solution?

Answer (score 1):

As Jesse says, you can't use INDIRECT to refer to closed workbooks. There is no other formula solution unless you use add-in functions. INDIRECT.EXT works with closed workbooks but you need to download `MOREFUNC` addin to get that function, google Morefunc

Comment: Thank you. Is there a VBA solution?

Answer (score 1):

See [INDIRECT and closed workbooks](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/01/indirect-and-closed-workbooks/) at Dick's Blog

Harlan Grove's [Pull function](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.excel.worksheet.functions/msg/e249f6c074a3adfd) and opening the workbook directly via VBA for large scale manipulation are the two most commonly used methods